# Spread operator function Graphql?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql

What is `... on?` when used in graphql. Is there another way to write it? When I use it in my vue apollo I get a `ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 400`

```
  projects(orderBy: order_DESC) {
    order
    projectCode
    name
    tags(orderBy: name_ASC) {
      name
    }
    projectContent {
      ... on ProjectSlider {
        image {
          url
        }
      }
      ... on ProjectVideo {
        video {
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is similar to the JavaScript spread operator, which is used for a similar purpose: to assign the keys and values of one object to another. These three dots instruct GraphQL to assign the fields from the fragment to the current selection set.

You can read more [here](https://moonhighway.com/graphql-fragments)